# Range of a continuous operator into the range of balls

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $P: H_{1} \rightarrow H_{2}$ be a bounded linear operator between two Hilbert spaces. Is it true that the following holds:

$$cl(Ran(P)) = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} cl(P(B_{1}(n)), $$

where $cl$ denotes the closure, and $B_{1}(n)$ represents the ball of radius $n$ in $H_{1}$. The basic topological argument shows $\subset$ is true, but I am not sure about the opposite direction.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, if $P$ is any compact operator on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space with dense range (say multiplication along the diagonal by $\frac{1}{n}$ on $l^2(\mathbb{N})$). Then $\mathrm{cl}(P(B(n)))$ is compact for all $n$, whence it has empty interior. By Baire category theorem, the RHS $\cup_n \mathrm{cl}(P(B(n)))$ then has empty interior, but the LHS $\mathrm{cl}(\mathrm{range}(P))$ is the entirety of $H$, so they can’t be equal.

Comment: In fact, I just realized, for any operator $P$ between Hilbert spaces, using the fact that the unit ball is weakly compact, we already have $P(B(n))$ is closed for all $n$, so the RHS is just the range of $P$.